# JavaScript function that flips brackets direction

Tags: javascript, function, replace

I have these strings:

```
)hello(
this has ]some text[
flip }any{ brackets
even with )))]multiple[((( brackets
```

As you can see, the brackets are all in the wrong direction.

I want to run a function called `flipBracketsDirection()` for each string, so the result will be this:

```
flipBracketsDirection(')hello(');
// should return:  (hello)

flipBracketsDirection('this has ]some text[');
// should return:  this has [some text]

flipBracketsDirection('flip }any{ brackets');
// should return:  flip {any} brackets

flipBracketsDirection('even with )))]multiple[((( brackets');
// should return:  even with ((([multiple]))) brackets
```

Note: it's totally fine if the direction flipped at ALL times. So this is fine too:

```
flipBracketsDirection('flip (it) anyway');
// should return:  flip )it( anyway
```

My attempt:

```
function flipBracketsDirection(str: string) {
  return str
    // flip () brackets
    .replace(/\(/g, 'tempBracket').replace(/\)/g, '(').replace(/tempBracket/g, ')')

    // flip [] brackets
    .replace(/\[/g, 'tempBracket').replace(/\]/g, '[').replace(/tempBracket/g, ']')

    // flip {} brackets
    .replace(/\{/g, 'tempBracket').replace(/\}/g, '{').replace(/tempBracket/g, '}')
    ;
}
```

I'm wondering if this is the best way to create the function?

Comment: So, what have you tried? Can you show your best attempt at solving this?. Showing effort to try to solve a question makes others more likely to help.

Comment: Hold on a couple of minutes, I will paste my attempt.

Comment: Hey tucuxi, I have updated my answer and added an example for my working function. Is there a better way to write it?

Comment: Seems like you already got an optimum solution.

Comment: This should probably go on the code review stack exchange instead of here

Comment: Would fail with `"evil input that breaks your code (because tempBracket was there)"`.

Comment: Thanks Sean! I wasn't aware of that forum. I have opened a question there: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244018/javascript-function-that-flips-brackets-direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently performs 6 regular expression substitutions (which require 1 pass each), and fails on strings that contain the text `tempBracket` (as noted by @Kaiido in comments).

This should be quicker because it makes a single pass. If all characters are ASCII, the `flip` function could be rewritten to use a look-up table, which would make it branch-free and potentially even faster.

```js
function flipBracketsDirection(str) {
  function flip(c) {
    switch (c) {
      case '(': return ')';
      case ')': return '(';
      case '[': return ']';
      case ']': return '[';
      case '{': return '}';
      case '}': return '{';
      default: return c;
    }
  }
  return Array.from(str).map(c => flip(c)).join('');
}    

// testcases
let test = (x) => console.log(flipBracketsDirection(x));
test('flip (it) anyway');
test(')hello(');
test('this has ]some text[');
test('flip }any{ brackets');
test('even with )))]multiple[((( brackets');
```

Comment: Hey tucuxi, I'd love to select your answer as the correct one because I think its the most readable and still works perfectly, with small performance issues. Can you post your answer to this post as well? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244018/javascript-function-that-flips-brackets-direction/244021#244021

Comment: @Elron I can post it there for completion, but I still think that the accepted answer is better in "codereview" sense, because my answer rewrites your code more than refactoring the regular expressions does.

Comment: I agree that the accepted answer is great (and the best one). However, knowing more ways to achieve this can be great learning for all readers. I think your code is less sophisticated, more human friendly, and it's just for people who don't want to use regex. Sharing your way would be cool.

Comment: Thanks - I shared it yesterday